# Raspberry PI: How to display something without keyboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have my Raspberry PI (2B) connected to a monitor, but now it asks for my password but the problem is: I don't have a USB keyboard, but SSH access.

So how can I display something on it, like a video?

Comment: well, if you are sure ssh daemon is running in the Pi and you know the IP address of the PI (assuming it is configured right),  you could ssh into the Pi and do all sorts of things. Edit your question with what you'd like to achieve and what have you done. Did you install the OS on pi?

Comment: I have raspbian installed the ip and it's fully configured. I only want it to show something via hdmi, like a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of digging on this, after getting interested in it again, and I found [this artice](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html) that explains how to auto-start and run a program on the Raspberry PI and it works for me.

I wrote a web server in PHP so I can do some things with the screen now.